# make Media Player Classic autoplay next when opening a single file (instead of looping)

Tags: media-player-classic

If I open a video folder in Media Player Classic, when a video finishes it will automatically start playing the next video in the folder. If I open a single file, it loops back to the beginning when the video ends. Can I make it start the next video instead? Currently I have to hit the "next" button to start the next video when opening a single file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it in playback option?
"View -> Options -> Playback -> set "Play" to 1 times -> set After Playback to "Play next file in the folder".

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried setting it in playback option? "View -> Options -> Playback -> set "Play" to 1 times -> set After Playback to "Play next file in the folder".

It is now "Additionally add to playlist" set to similar files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1216373)